# Is there a way for changing triple value in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dataset

**Why arguments in Kotlin `Triple` class define as `val`?**

```
public data class Triple<out A, out B, out C>(
    public val first: A,
    public val second: B,
    public val third: C
) : Serializable {

    /**
     * Returns string representation of the [Triple] including its [first], [second] and [third] values.
     */
    public override fun toString(): String = "($first, $second, $third)"
}
```

**Is there a way for changing `first` , `second` or `third` value after we set them ?**

```
private var mSituation=Triple<Boolean,Boolean,Boolean>(first = false, second = false, third = false)

mSituation.first=true // val cannot be reassigned
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `copy` method of data classes

```
private var mSituation = Triple(first = false, second = false, third = false)

mSituation = mSituation.copy(first = true)
```

But you shouldn't use `Triple` this way, no one will understand what these values mean, even you will forget in a few weeks

Create your own data class with meaningful property names and `var` modifier, if you need it

Answer (score 1):

Properties in Kotlin classes can be declared either as mutable using the *var* keyword, or as read-only using the *val* keyword.

```
public class Triple< A>(
    public var first: A
)  

fun main() {
    var mSituation=Triple<Boolean>(first = false)

    mSituation.first=true 
    println("Hello, world!!!")
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html